# type in mongodb not filtering record properly

Tags: python, mongodb, types, mongodb-compass

**Applying Filter**

```
{'info.version': { $type: "string" }}
```

**Output of above filter**

```
c
python
java
ubuntu
```

**MongoDB Version:** 3.6.3

Data in MongoDB(Consider every list element as single document)

```json
[
  {
    "name": "c",
    "info": {
      "version": "2.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "python",
    "info": {
      "version": [
        "2.0",
        "3.0"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "java",
    "info": {
      "version": [
        "11.0"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ubuntu",
    "info": {
      "version":"20"
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
c(Record)
ubuntu(record)
```

Is I am missing something while applying filter?

Comment: version is string in few records and array in few records. Change this in to one of the format

Comment: I am comparing which is string or array i need to filter out record if that is string. The data should be in different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this

```
await db.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                "info.version": { $type: "string",$not: {$type: "array" } }
            },
        }

    ]).toArray()
```